# How to set up a computer to use an ISP provided public address behind my router

Tags: nat, internet, ip

We are setting a web application in our local network, but due to the large number of our users, we would like to give our application server a public ip address while using it behind our router. 
We don't want our application server to interfere with other computers in the subnetwork.
P.S.: I am not a network savvy.

Thank you for your kind answers.

Comment: Use a VLAN for the server. There is no way I know of to use an IP behind a router. I won't get into detail since this isn't my field of expertise.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use static NAT to assign a public IP address to a privately addressed Web application server.  Putting the workload on a different VLAN or public IP address does not fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to get a second router, assign it an unused public IP address, and forward the appropriate ports to your server.  The server would be physically separated from the rest of your network.   As an example, lets say you have a cable modem with a built in 4 port switch and a block of 5 usable IPs 100.0.0.2 through 100.0.0.6.   You'd plug the WAN ports of the two routers into the cable modem, assign 100.0.0.2 to one router and 100.0.0.3 to the other.   To access the server, you'd either have to physically be in front of it, use a program like TeamViewer, or forward port 3389 to the server so you can use RDP.

A more sophisticated way of doing it would to get a router supports 1 to 1 NAT.  That would allow you assign one public IP address to your server and another for the rest of your network using only one router. Depending on the router, you could either create a separate sub-interface for your server to keep it separate or use VLANs.

If you don't have much experience, I'd probably go with option A unless you have a need for computers on your network to be able to access that server locally.